# Unable to create a new outlet connection for UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I have an iPad app, using Storyboards, XCode 4.5.  On one of my scenes, I have a UIImage that I am trying to create a @property and make a connection to it.  So I do a CTRL drag from the UIImage to the .h file.  I have cleaned the app several times (CMD+OPTION+K), and get this message:
[image]

I've never had this problem before.  First of all, what is causing this and secondly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the derived data for this app.

1) Close the project, but keep Xcode open.

2) Go to Xcode's Organizer and select the Projects pane.

3) Delete the Derived Data for the project (if it doesn't disappear after the first delete, try doing it again).

4) Shut down / Restart Xcode, do another "clean," and try again.

Comment: Working on it now... had lots of stuff to delete... going to do restart now... I'll be back...

Comment: Now I get this:  Unknown class ClientViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: I found I was missing the files... added them back in and it works fine now... thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me once.

1. Close & reopen Xcode
2. Make Sure that the Nib file class is set correctly to the appropriate class name

Comment: Closed and re-opened it a few times already... and there is no Nib file; this is using Storyboards... thanks anyway.

Comment: Check if your ClientViewController implementation (.m) file, is included in the "Compile Sources" build phase

Comment: Also you can remove the .h/.m ClientViewController files and add them back to the project as another solution

Comment: ClientViewController.m file is in the build phase...  How do I "remove" the .h/.m files without deleting them? remove the references and then add them back in?

Comment: Yes. Just remove the references (not delete), then Add Existing Files. (Recheck again that the .m file is in the compile sources, after adding back, if it's not, drag and drop the main file to add it.